# All Items Get Out Of Stock After A Certain Amount Of Time - Can't Figure Out Why?

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock

I'm working on a website for a client and right before publishing the website, I noticed that all the products went out of stock itself. So I put them all back in stock and everything looked fine, but when I checked back after a few hours all the products were back out of stock.

I tried a few times to re-enter the stock quantities, re-index and clear the cache, but I'm still having this weird issue - everything looks fine until like 2-3 hours later everything goes out of stock.

Any suggestion what could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check there is any third party integration like erp , and check with change api password.

Comment: It's a website I took over from another developer and I'm not really sure what all the installed extensions are... You can have a look at the screenshots of the [site modules here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0mNYk9tnrnQZ05XazhXLXFRdGc) and the [Magento Connect extention manager here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0mNYk9tnrnQd09nUmNYYjZvNFU)

Comment: Any suggestion, please??????????????

Comment: Then check with changing api key